# Opening a file in VLC from search bar in Windows 7 changed how all files are opened

Tags: windows-7, file-association

I opened a media file using 'Open with VLC media Player' after searching for the file from the start menu. Now all the media files are opening in VLC. I tried changing this using 'Choose a default program', but when I open with any other program all the files are opening in that.

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck 'Always use the selected program to open this kind of file' from the 'Open with' dialogue to avoid this behaviour, or use the checkbox to reset the file type association to its previous value. You can also manually restore these settings from the control panel under 'Default Programs'. You cannot specify a program for a single media file though, the settigns will take effect for all files with the same extension.

[image: Open with]